# "Type 'debo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list"

Tags: apt

I was trying to install spotify for Ubuntu when this error appeared:

```
E: Type 'debo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: I tried, but i still have the same problem.

Comment: pastebin or post the entire contents of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Make sure all lines begin with "deb" or "deb-src" or are comments (they start with "#"), there should be at least one that says "debo" which is a typing error.

Comment: When i open it with gedit, the file spotify.list appears empty, nothing write inside.

Comment: Well that's odd. Are you sure about the error message being `E: Type 'debo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

Comment: WAIT! I solved it, maybe it takes time to take effect that change. Im a new user of ubuntu, so im a bit confused with it. Thank you manu for your help! Have a great day!

Comment: @user3242120 You have to open the file as root (sudo) or it is empty. If you did not edit the file it was likely fixed if you ran the sed command I gave you.

Comment: Editing a file by hand is normally a Bad Idea™

Answer (score 2):

The most direct solution is using:

```
sudo sed -i'.bk' 's/^ *debo /deb /' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

It would remove the extra "o" in your sources type. It is important that you notify the one that provided that file or instructions to create it, so they fix the issue.